# How to handle data from JsonResult in controller as a JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, .net

I have an app that uploads and reads excel files.

[image]

the controller returns JSON

```
 public ActionResult OnPost(IFormFile file)
    {
        List<FlightModel> flights = new List<FlightModel>();
        System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {
                while (reader.Read()) //Each row of the file
                {
                    flights.Add(new FlightModel
                    { Side = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), REG = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()
                    ,
                        Actual_Date = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                        Actual_Time = reader.GetValue(3).ToString()
                    });
                }

            }
        }

        return new JsonResult(flights);

    }
```

And it will be displayed in the view as JSON objects. I want to do some operation on the data using JS, so how to return it as a js object. I already tried $get but because I have to upload the file first the method won't work unless I have the data on a dataset?

Comment: are you trying to do some data maniupation on the json array that you get after you upload the file?

Comment: Yes, but I think the best way is to capture the data from the controller through $get then I can play with it before sending it to the view @Saravanan